# How to load HTML string on UIWebView using swift?

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

The Following is the Code I am using to load HTML String on web view:-

```
let urlAsString = "https://here is my url"            
var encryptedStr: String = "merchant_id=\(merchantId)&order_id=\(orderId)&redirect_url=\(redirectUrl)&cancel_url=\(cancelUrl)&language=EN&billing_name=\(billingName)&billing_address=\(billingAddress)&billing_city=\(billingCity)&billing_state=\(billingState)&billing_zip=\(billingZipCode)&billing_country=\(billingCountry)&billing_tel=\(billingTel)&billing_email=\(billingEmail)&delivery_name=\(deliveryName)&delivery_address=\(deliveryAddress)&delivery_city=\(deliveryCity)&delivery_state=\(deliveryState)&delivery_zip=\(deliveryZipCode)&delivery_country=\(deliveryCountry)&delivery_tel=\(deliveryTel)&merchant_param1=additional Info.&merchant_param2=additional Info.&merchant_param3=additional Info.&merchant_param4=additional Info.&payment_option=\(payOptId)&card_type=\(cardType)&card_name=\(cardName)&data_accept=\(dataAcceptedAt)&enc_val=\(encVal!)&issuing_bank=\(issuingBank)&access_code=\(accessCode)&mobile_no=\(mobileNo)&emi_plan_id=\(emiPlanId)&emi_tenure_id=\(emiTenureId)"

print("encryptedStr :: ",encryptedStr)

if isSaveCard!
{
    encryptedStr = encryptedStr + ("&saveCard=Y")
}

let myRequestData = NSData(bytes: encryptedStr, length: encryptedStr.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8))

print("\n\n\n myRequestData :: ",myRequestData.description)

let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: urlAsString)!)

request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
request.setValue(urlAsString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Referer")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = myRequestData as Data
print("\n\n\nwebview :: ",request)

let transResData: Data? = try? NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, returning: nil) // here i am not getting any data

print("transResData ::: \(String(describing: transResData))") 

let transResString = String(data: transResData!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)
print("\n\n\n*******************************Payload Response Start*******************************\n")
print("\(String(describing: transResString))") // it gives blank space no any HTML Code
print("\n**********************************Payload Response End********************************\n\n\n")
viewWeb.loadHTMLString(transResString!, baseURL: nil)
```

But not getting any data in variable named **transResData**. It gives 0 Bytes as Output. Please provide any Code that can Help me in getting Output.
TIA.

Comment: then obviously the issue is in calling the request, not in loading the html in UIWebView.. since you did not gave us a url that you are trying to access, we cannot replicate it.. thus my only advice to you would be to take Postman (or another tool for testing REST requests) and test out the endpoint (and then compare your working Postman request with what you create in swift - I had once a problem with a request just because the data were formatted differently)

Comment: @MilanNosáľ because of privacy concern not able to share URL. Sorry for that. Will try with POSTMAN n check it once. Thank you.

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/EmSEFephgTZKbtTvrmNtSE